# How to add action inheriting a workflow in openerp?

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

I need to add an action in the account_voucher workflow

```
    <record id="act_done" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf"/>
        <field name="name">done</field>
        <field name="action">proforma_voucher()</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
    </record>
```

The action is "reference_action()", but i dont know how to do it. I tried whit this

```
    <record id="act_reference_done" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="account_voucher.act_done"/>
        <field name="action">reference_action()</field>
    </record>
```

Thing is that i have to put the column "name" or i violate a not-null constraint, but if i do that i just add another activity with the same name and i dont over-ride the other one.

Any tip on how to correct inherit and edit a workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing wrong to override/inherit workflow activity.
To override workflow activity, you have to use same xml id with module name where it is created.

Try this:

```
<record id="module_name.act_done" model="workflow.activity">
    <field name="wkf_id" ref="module_name.wkf"/>
    <field name="name">done</field>
    <field name="action">proforma_voucher()
    reference_action()
    </field>
    <field name="kind">function</field>
    <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
</record>
```